# Why converting array to dictionary reducing number of records?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I got array which look like that:

```
first = [  6.50480320e+05   3.00891760e+05   2.06200000e+01   5.86400395e-01
   6.50480188e+05   3.00892264e+05   2.03518509e+01]
```

I convert it to dictionary taking 4th column as a key using this function:

```
 d1 = dict((x[4], x[0:]) for x in first)
```

But when i check the length i got bizarre result:

```
print(len(first)) #len = 99522
print(len(d1)) #len = 3285
```

However when i try to use it on similar array length was similar

```
sec = [  6.50277398e+05   1.00000000e+00]
d2 = dict((x[0], x[1:]) for x in sec)

print(len(sec)) #len = 108371
print(len(d2)) #len = 107762
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Dictionaries have unique keys. I'm guessing you are overwriting your dictionary with duplicates from the array.

Comment: Wow that could be it ! Is there a way to not overwriting duplicated keys?

Comment: no dictionaries don't work that way.  If this is required, you may want to resort to a 2d array -- numpy.array()

Comment: damit, so i need to rewrite me function to use set's or something different.

Comment: sets are also unique...

Comment: You can also try using an array of tuples.

Comment: i will try to use just one dictionary and array and use it us look up table